# How to save data into server at a time toggle switch on/off selected values?

Tags: android, toggleswitch

Hi in the below code i have a save button in that contains one toggle button names are day/night

simple-switch means its toggle button with day/night names.

if am toggle to day am selecting some values and then next toggle to night mode then am selecting some values.
In day contains 12 values and night contains 12 values.

suppose user selected either day or night i can able to 12 values.but my question if the user frist selected day values 12 and the then toggle to night and selected values are 12 and then press on save button .

How to pass 24 values to the server in my case

save/java:

```
mSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(simpleSwitch1.isOn()) {
                    ActiveProgressDialog();
                    getCCTAndIntensityValues(API.SET_APP_SCHEDULE);
                    //getCCTAndIntensityValuesSet();
                }
                else{
                    ActiveProgressDialog();
                    getCCTAndIntensityValues(API.SET_APP_SCHEDULE);
                }

            }

        });

public void getCCTAndIntensityValues (String schedulerType) {

            int cct1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT1.getProgress()));
            int cct2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT2.getProgress()));
            int cct3 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT3.getProgress()));
            int cct4 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT4.getProgress()));
            int cct5 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT5.getProgress()));
            int cct6 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT6.getProgress()));
            int cct7 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT7.getProgress()));
            int cct8 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT8.getProgress()));
            int cct9 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT9.getProgress()));
            int cct10 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT10.getProgress()));
            int cct11 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT11.getProgress()));
            int cct12 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT12.getProgress()));


            int intensity1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty1.getProgress()));
            int intensity2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty2.getProgress()));
            int intensity3 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty3.getProgress()));
            int intensity4 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty4.getProgress()));
            int intensity5 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty5.getProgress()));
            int intensity6 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty6.getProgress()));
            int intensity7 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty7.getProgress()));
            int intensity8 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty8.getProgress()));
            int intensity9 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty9.getProgress()));
            int intensity10 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty10.getProgress()));
            int intensity11 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty11.getProgress()));
            int intensity12 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty12.getProgress()));

            try {

                ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<>();
                number.add(intensity1);
                number.add(intensity2);
                number.add(intensity3);
                number.add(intensity4);
                number.add(intensity5);
                number.add(intensity6);
                number.add(intensity7);
                number.add(intensity8);
                number.add(intensity9);
                number.add(intensity10);
                number.add(intensity11);
                number.add(intensity12);

                JSONArray numberJson = new JSONArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++) {

                    numberJson.put(i, number.get(i));

                }

                ArrayList<Integer> cctvalues = new ArrayList<>();
                cctvalues.add(cct1);
                cctvalues.add(cct2);
                cctvalues.add(cct3);
                cctvalues.add(cct4);
                cctvalues.add(cct5);
                cctvalues.add(cct6);
                cctvalues.add(cct7);
                cctvalues.add(cct8);
                cctvalues.add(cct9);
                cctvalues.add(cct10);
                cctvalues.add(cct11);
                cctvalues.add(cct12);


                JSONArray cctJsonArray = new JSONArray();
                if(cctJsonArray !=null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < cctvalues.size(); i++) {

                        cctJsonArray.put(i, cctvalues.get(i));

                    }
                }
                RequestAsyntask mRequestAsyntask = new RequestAsyntask(mContext);

                try {
                    RequestBody requestBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                            .add("light_id", lightid)
                            .add("intensity", numberJson.toString())
                            .add("cct",cctJsonArray.toString() ).build();
                    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(BASE_URL + schedulerType).post(requestBody).build();

                    mRequestAsyntask.runDataRetriver(request, false);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Sending---" + BASE_URL + schedulerType + "\n" + "light_id:" + lightid + "\n" + "intensity:" + numberJson.toString() + "\n" + "cct:" + cctJsonArray.toString());

                    mRequestAsyntask.setResponseListener(new ResponseCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(String response) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Response:" + response);

                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello @jyo cha you are already posting 24 values into your request which is intensity and cct json arrays.

Comment: @BasitAli for both day and night means 24 values for intensity and 24 values for cct

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with this

```
private JSONArray numberJson = new JSONArray();
private JSONArray cctJsonArray = new JSONArray();
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled
    getCCTAndIntensityValues(API.SET_APP_SCHEDULE);
                    //getCCTAndIntensityValuesSet();
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
    getCCTAndIntensityValues(API.SET_APP_SCHEDULE);
        }
    }
});
mSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ActiveProgressDialog();
    RequestAsyntask mRequestAsyntask = new RequestAsyntask(mContext);

                try {
                    RequestBody requestBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                            .add("light_id", lightid)
                            .add("intensity", numberJson.toString())
                            .add("cct",cctJsonArray.toString() ).build();
                    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(BASE_URL + 
    schedulerType).post(requestBody).build();

                    mRequestAsyntask.runDataRetriver(request, false);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Sending---" + BASE_URL + schedulerType + "\n" + 
    "light_id:" + lightid + "\n" + "intensity:" + numberJson.toString() + "\n" + "cct:" + 
    cctJsonArray.toString());

                    mRequestAsyntask.setResponseListener(new ResponseCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(String response) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Response:" + response);

                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
public void getCCTAndIntensityValues (String schedulerType) {

            int cct1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT1.getProgress()));
            int cct2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT2.getProgress()));
            int cct3 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT3.getProgress()));
            int cct4 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT4.getProgress()));
            int cct5 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT5.getProgress()));
            int cct6 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT6.getProgress()));
            int cct7 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT7.getProgress()));
            int cct8 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT8.getProgress()));
            int cct9 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT9.getProgress()));
            int cct10 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT10.getProgress()));
            int cct11 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT11.getProgress()));
            int cct12 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT12.getProgress()));


            int intensity1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty1.getProgress()));
            int intensity2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty2.getProgress()));
            int intensity3 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty3.getProgress()));
            int intensity4 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty4.getProgress()));
            int intensity5 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty5.getProgress()));
            int intensity6 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty6.getProgress()));
            int intensity7 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty7.getProgress()));
            int intensity8 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty8.getProgress()));
            int intensity9 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty9.getProgress()));
            int intensity10 = 
    Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty10.getProgress()));
            int intensity11 = 
    Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty11.getProgress()));
            int intensity12 = 
    Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty12.getProgress()));

            try {

                ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<>();
                number.add(intensity1);
                number.add(intensity2);
                number.add(intensity3);
                number.add(intensity4);
                number.add(intensity5);
                number.add(intensity6);
                number.add(intensity7);
                number.add(intensity8);
                number.add(intensity9);
                number.add(intensity10);
                number.add(intensity11);
                number.add(intensity12);



                for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++) {

                    numberJson.put(i, number.get(i));

                }

                ArrayList<Integer> cctvalues = new ArrayList<>();
                cctvalues.add(cct1);
                cctvalues.add(cct2);
                cctvalues.add(cct3);
                cctvalues.add(cct4);
                cctvalues.add(cct5);
                cctvalues.add(cct6);
                cctvalues.add(cct7);
                cctvalues.add(cct8);
                cctvalues.add(cct9);
                cctvalues.add(cct10);
                cctvalues.add(cct11);
                cctvalues.add(cct12);

                if(cctJsonArray !=null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < cctvalues.size(); i++) {
                        cctJsonArray.put(i, cctvalues.get(i));
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer .In your code it will excute either if or else condition.but want both conditions to be excuted at the time of save button pressed then i can 48 values i.e. 24 intensity and 24 cct values

Comment: any help from your side

Comment: @jyo cha can you please also share your layout image so i can properly understand your particular case. Thanks